# 'AllowAnonymous' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

Everything worked fine until I installed (Package Manager Console) the postal package, then uninstalled and installed an older version.

Now I get an error where it previously was not.
Error:

`The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymous' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are missing the reference to `System.Web.Http` assembly in your project?

So you need to:

- Add the reference to `System.Web.Http`;
- Add `using System.Web.Http;` to your controller;

To add Reference you need to do next steps:

- In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project node and click **Add
  Reference**.
- In the **Add Reference dialog box**, select the tab Assemblies, and enter  `System.Web.Http` into search on the right side.
- Select the component `System.Web.Http`, and then click OK.

Link:

[**How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: I can not install `System.Web.Http`. Click on instal in Nuget and nothing happens. Likewise, in Package Manager Console.

Comment: You don't need to install System.Web.Http, it is already installed in GAC.

Comment: you just need to add reference to your project. In solution explored find your project, inside project find References, right click on it and Add Reference. In dialog use search.

Comment: It works. But now it appears `The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You are also missing System.Web.Mvc assembly. Do same steps and add this assembly too.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for 2021 on .Net 5.0, turns out I was missing this line:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After reinstalling a package, MVC 5 was removed and then MVC 3 was added! The following command fixed the problem:

```
PM> update-package
```

Comment: Same here. I've used old version of MVC library.