# AllowAnonymous could not be found

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, authorization

I'm following [this](https://garywoodfine.com/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication-tutorial/) tutorial on adding JWT authentication into my dotnet core web api. I've added the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute a method in my controller, however I'm getting an error stating the type or namespace cannot be found.

> The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymous' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) [GitWrap]

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390033/allowanonymous-could-not-be-found) answer to the same question, and after following the suggestions (to add a reference to `System.Web.Http`), I still have the same error.

Note, I'm working with VSCode (which I'm quite unfamiliar with), and added the package with the following command:

```
dotnet add package System.Web.Http
```

The lined posted also states to add a reference to `System.We.Mvc`, which I've done using the `dotnet add package` command. And finally, I've restored the packages with `dotnet restore`, but I *still* have the same error.

Can anyone please point out how properly add a reference to the required package in dotnet core, so I can use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to use a `System.Web` package in a .NET Core application? That's extremely wrong and will not work. You are looking for the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` (***alll*** ASP.NET Core packages are prefixed with `Microsoft.AspNetCore`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thank you very much for sharing this, much appreciated.

Comment: Installing package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App from nuget fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the statement `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`, so it works. That's how it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).